# What is the difference between "linger" and "loiter"?

Tags: differences

What is the difference between *linger* and *loiter*?

Comment: A big one is that "loiter" is often used in a pejorative sense.  "Linger" hardly ever.

Comment: @HotLicks Ok, thanks! Can you maybe tell me more of a definition comparison? For example: "x is x but y is y" - x and y being the words and difference. Not exactly how people use it but how the words are different by definition

Comment: Have you consulted some dictionaries?  What about their definitions are not clear to you?  Without your own research, this question may be closed as "off topic" for lack of research.

Comment: The difference is somewhat subtle.  If you linger it usually implies that you had some reason for being at your current location, but have continued to be there after the reason has passed.  Eg, you may arrange to meet a friend at a coffee shop, then linger after the friend leaves, as you finish your coffee.  With "loiter" there's less of an implication of a "expired" reason for your presence (though the difference is not black-and-white).  You may have just plopped yourself down on a park bench and be loitering there, or you may have been there to watch the sunset and lingered.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I have looked in a dictionary and used google, but I still don't understand how because it appears to be subtle.

Comment: @HotLicks Awesome! That is what I was looking for. Could you maybe put that into an answer?

Comment: Please [edit] this to at least quote the definitions you've read. If you don't show evidence of research this will be closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is somewhat subtle.

If you linger it usually implies that you had some reason for being at your current location, but have continued to be there after the reason has passed. Eg, you may arrange to meet a friend at a coffee shop, then linger after the friend leaves, as you finish your coffee.

With "loiter" there's less of an implication of a "expired" reason for your presence (though the difference is not black-and-white). You may have just plopped yourself down on a park bench and be *loitering* there, or you may have been there to watch the sunset and *lingered*.

Note that in many cities there are "anti-loitering" laws, often written quite loosely, which allow the police to cite people who "loiter" in certain situations.  But as you can see, the basic definition of "loitering" is quite vague, and such laws are often used to harass individuals who are viewed as unsavory or undesirable.

Comment: I was going to make that point. In the UK *loitering* is an offence for which you can be arrested - usually worded *loitering with intent* - implying that the purpose of the loitering was to commit a crime. Unless you actually commit a crime it is unlikely it will ever lead to any charge. But the police can and do force people to 'move on' if they think they are standing around for no good reason. So *loitering* carries with it some criminal baggage. It is not a word one would use to mention that one's boss and his wife stayed late over dinner. But 'linger' can have a nice feel to it.

Comment: @WS2 - Same situation in the US, only in some cities actual arrests (and occasional beatings by police) are less than rare.

Answer (score 4):

Linger almost indicates that the person was invited but has outstayed their welcome whereas loiter is usually in reference to a person who is present without invitation